# Mathematica Fit to Polynomial does not work correctly

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, data-fitting

I am trying to fit data from a simulation to a polynomial. Luckily I do know the exact data and I know that my values are not bad at all!
However, when trying to fit the data to a polynomial function using mathematica, the outcome is not satisfying at all.
The (reduced) data compared to the exact data:

```
A = {{1, 4.20109`*^7}, {1.2214`, 5.92216`*^7}, {1.49182`, 
    9.21732`*^7}, {1.82212`, 1.60874`*^8}, {2.22554`, 
    3.21498`*^8}, {2.71828`, 7.4201`*^8}, {3.32012`, 
    2.01259`*^9}, {4.0552`, 6.24526`*^9}, {4.95303`, 
    2.2347`*^10}, {6.04965`, 9.13043`*^10}, {7.38906`, 
    4.12888`*^11}, {9.02501`, 2.03485`*^12}, {11.0232`, 
    1.07487`*^13}, {13.4637`, 5.98665`*^13}, {16.4446`, 
    3.49113`*^14}, {20.0855`, 1.96163`*^15}, {24.5325`, 
    1.15952`*^16}, {29.9641`, 8.46196`*^16}, {36.5982`, 
    5.93001`*^17}, {44.7012`, 2.86328`*^18}, {54.5982`, 
    1.56988`*^19}, {66.6863`, 8.60926`*^19}, {81.4509`, 
    4.95028`*^20}, {99.4843`, 2.56403`*^21}, {121.51`, 
    1.85016`*^22}};
InterFunc = Simplify[InterpolatingPolynomial[A, x]];
poly = Fit[A, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7, x^9}, x]
FindFit[A, 
 a + b*x + c*x^2 + d*x^3 + e*x^4 + l*x^5 + m*x^6 + h*x^7 + o*x^9, {a, 
  b, c, d, e, l, m, h, o}, x]

func = 10966470 + 12755136*x + 9092592*x^2 + 5269920*x^3 + 
   2435256*x^4 + 1059120*x^5 + 257880*x^6 + 94272*x^7 + 3504*x^9;

Show[ListLogPlot[A, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 LogPlot[{poly}, {x, 0, First[Last[A]]}, PlotStyle -> Orange], 
 LogPlot[{func}, {x, 0, First[Last[A]]}, PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

My first idea was to use the InterpolatingPolynomial command and reduce the indata to 10 so I get a polynomial of order 9. It does not work, neither do Fit or FindFit, although 'func' shows there exist a polynomial fitting the data well. 
Is there another way to do the fit properly? Mathematica uses the LeastSquare fit, is there anothe method that can be used?

Another more mathemtical question: A polynomial is well-behaving, why does the LeastSquare fails here?

Comment: The trouble is `FindFit` computes its error in linear space -- If you just want a good fit you should take the log of the data and fit to that.  If you really want that polynonal form you will need to work with the `NormFunction`  argument to `FindFit` to tell it to determine the error based on the log of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elaborating on my comment, here is a fit to the log of the data..

```
 fit = a + b x + c Sqrt[x ] /.
    FindFit[MapAt[Log, A, {All, 2}], a + b x + c Sqrt[x ] ,
         {a, b, c}, x]
 Show[{LogPlot[ Exp[fit] , {x, 0, 120}], ListLogPlot[A]}]
```

[image]

of course that fit is not the polynomial you wanted..

```
 E^(10.686624598376872 + 6.617878262099062*Sqrt[x] - 0.2731299046868744*x)
```

Here is a direct  polynomial fit using `NormFunction`

```
 fn =  Sum[ a[i] x^i, {i, 0, 9}];
 vars = CoefficientList[fn, x];
 fit = fn /. FindFit[A, fn, vars, x , NormFunction -> (Norm[Log[#]] &)]
 Show[{LogPlot[ fit , {x, 0, 120}], ListLogPlot[A]}]

  (* 1. + 1. x + 0.917982 x^2 + 1.76793 x^3 + 0.917982 x^4 + 1. x^5 + 4.36769 x^6 + 14.3472 x^7 + 133.75 x^8 + 3202.96 x^9 *)
```

This is very hit or miss, sometimes giving garbage depending on the order of the polynomial.

[image]

For reference here is the poor quality original fit:

[image]

The "error" where it looks bad is "only" order 10^17, which is basically negligible compared to any error at the high end of the data. (  The circled point is the maximum error on the plot ) Fitting in linear space is effectively fitting only to the large data values.

Comment: Yeap, that looks bette, but I need the polynomial :) 
But I am still confused: Why is it failing in linear space? E.g when reducing the date from xange 0 to 5 and perfoming linear fit and plot there is a huge error.

Comment: Okay thank you so much :) 
I see it now, the LeastSquare method minimises the absolute error over the whole function, so the error produced in the low-value area is still small..